# JAXB from Java to XML

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

My target is to get this xml marshalling Java objects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<ns2:cedolini xmlns:ns2="" data_produzione=""
 codice_sistema_emittente="">
<cedolino>
    <testata lingua="I">
        <info>
            <infoSoggetto></infoSoggetto>
            <infoIndirizzo></infoIndirizzo>
            <email></email>
        </info>
        <anagrafica cod="xxxxxxyyxyyxyyyx">
            <cognome></cognome>
            <nome></nome>
            <dataNascita></dataNascita>
            <via></via>
            <civico></civico>
            <cap></cap>
            <citta_residenza></citta_residenza>
            <provincia_residenza></provincia_residenza>
        </anagrafica>
    </testata>
</cedolino>
.
.
</ns2:cedolini>
```

My trouble is how to represent the list of object Cedolino.

```
<ns2:cedolini xmlns:ns2="" data_produzione=""
 codice_sistema_emittente="">
    <cedolino>
      ....
    </cedolino>
    <cedolino>
      ....
    </cedolino>
</ns2:cedolini>
```

In my mind the solution to represent each Cedolino object is something like that.

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class Cedolino{

  private Testata testata;
  private Info info;
  private Anagrafica anagrafica;

  public get and set methods...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your xml to Xsd ,
follow below link :
https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

Once you get the generated xsd, save that in your project,
now generate POJO using xsd.

**GENERATING POJO USING xsd:**

1.in eclipse goto file -> new-> Other-> JAXB classes from schema.
provide package name, where you want your pojo to be generated.

Comment: I used this solution. It generated one class Cedolini.java which has nested classes. I don't know if it is a correct solution.

Comment: It is correct, i have been using it for a very long time

Comment: Did you achieve what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it. First some POJOs:

```
@XmlName("ns2:cedolini")
public class Cedolini {
    @XmlName("cedolino")
    public List<Cedolino> cedolinos;
}

public class Cedolino {
    public Testata testata;
}

public class Testata {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String lingua;
    public Info info;
    public Anagrafica anagrafica;
}
public class Info {}
public class Anagrafica {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String cod;
}
```

Then serialize and print:

```
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Cedolini i = simple.fromXml(xml, Cedolini.class);
System.out.println(i.cedolinos.get(0).testata.lingua + " : " + i.cedolinos.get(0).testata.anagrafica.cod);
```

This will print:

```
I : xxxxxxyyxyyxyyyx
```

SimpleXml is in maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Cedolini class should have a List of Cedolino object, not a list of Testata object